# Speech to text using url of mp3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I'm trying to find a solution for Speech to text of an mp3 file, but I only want to pass in the URL. I don't want to download the file & upload to S3 for AWS or GS for GCP etc.

Is there any such service I can access programmatically to do this? Maybe Google Speech to text can do this somehow...but I can't find anything in the docs.

Any help would be great if this is something someone else has tried.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Cloud offers 500 minutes/month of free speech to text conversions. No credit card required! In their free, lite plan, you can use NodeJS, PHP, storage S3-like, databases, and many other always free products.
It never expires. Start from here: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/free